# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:property-placeholder'

Tags: spring

could anyone help me resolving the following error as i am new to spring?

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no         
declaration can be found for element 'context:property-placeholder'.
```

I have the following configuration in applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

<bean id="dataSource"class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
<property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
<context:property-placeholder location="src/jdbc.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 42):

Spring provides a bunch of additional name-spaces that provide short-hand ways to do things - things like tx (transactions), util (utils), mvc (spring MVC declarations):

To use one, you have to set up the schema mapping in your XML file. If this is done, you get basic code-completion (your IDE may provide more). .

***In your declaration context was not set-up/mapped.***

Change your declaration to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


</beans>
```

You can also set up your own namespaces for in-house components, if you wish.

Comment: Hi Jasper. I have a similar XML problem. Can you please help me ? Question is at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723413/xml-problems-in-java-project Thanks.

Comment: Hi @BoratSagdiyev, I'm sorry but I don't work much with Spring lately. . I was able to answer the question above because it relates to 'spring core'. . I'm sure someone can help though.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring >= 3.1, use PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer rather than the old.

Workaround:
Replace

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:sport.properties"/>
```

BY

`

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location">
<value>classpath:sport.properties</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If using Spring Framework 5.2 or higher, you can load variables from a properties file using the alternative:

```xml
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:sport.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

So your full XML file would look something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It will serve the same functionality as `context:property-placeholder`