# XML problems in java project

Tags: java, xml, spring

This is a question about xml files in a java project. I have a spring 4 project which can be downloaded from here - http://www.perfmath.com/spring/soba_zip/soba4_download_1.zip

Under src > main > webapp > web-inf > lib, the `soba-webflow.xml` file is giving me many errors. I googled this and saw similar errors, but I did not find a method to correct it in my case. Please help.

**Error 1 -**

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'webflow:flow-registry'.
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be 
     read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

**Error 2 -**

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'webflow:flow-executor'.
```

**Code snippet from the xml file -**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.4.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    <property name ="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="flowHandlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
     <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
     </bean>

    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry">
        <webflow:flow-location
            path="/WEB-INF/flows/onlineService/onlineService.xml" />
        <webflow:flow-location
            path="/WEB-INF/flows/customerSearch/customerSearch.xml" />
        <webflow:flow-location
            path="/WEB-INF/flows/customerDetails/customerDetails.xml" />
        <webflow:flow-location
            path="/WEB-INF/flows/transferMoney/transferMoney.xml" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>

    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
        <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
            <webflow:listener ref="securityFlowExecutionListener" />
            <webflow:listener ref="jpaFlowExecutionListener" />
        </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
    </webflow:flow-executor>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the soba4_download_1.zip and observed that in pom.xml  element you are refering to 2.3.3 version of webflow:

```
    <spring.webflow.version>2.3.3.RELEASE</spring.webflow.version>
```

But where as in your soba-webflow.xml, you are referring to schema location of spring-webflow-config-2.4.xsd.

To resolve this you have 2 options:

**Option 1:**

Since you already have 2.3.3 webflow version, change spring-webflow-config schema location to:

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
```

**Option 2:**

Upgrade to webflow 2.4 version. In  spring-webflow-2.4.0.RC1.jar, you have spring-webflow-config-2.4.xsd file included.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting these errors from the IDE, make sure that the schema document `http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd` is accessible from it (network connection, proxy settings etc.). I could load the XML successfully in my Eclipse.